# prevent apt dependency from being satisfied (permanently)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, debian, apt, mailman

I want to install mailman (just to use it's mail archiving feature) but Ubuntu wants to pull down a load of extra dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install mailman 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2.2-common
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom spamassassin lynx listadmin
```

Is there any way to mark those packages ( apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2.2-common ) as never to be installed? This is not 2002 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mailman depends on either `apache2` or the `httpd` metapackage, so pick a webserver that fancies you and provides `httpd`.

Edit: You can get a list of packages providing `httpd` with the command `aptitude search '~Phttpd'` and in case that you really don't want any web server installed (and risk a broken system), you could construct a dummy package with the help of the tools in the `equivs` package.

Comment: Didn't realize I hadn't installed lighttpd. What are these tools in the equivs package ( got a link? ).